# Training a neural network to learn polynomial equation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have created a data set of y ~ x**2

[image]

However, when I train a neural network, it just can't fit a quadratic equation.

[image]

This is my model.

```
model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)]
)

loss = tf.keras.losses.mse
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)

model2.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=tf.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError())
model2.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_train, -1), y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=1)
```

My thought process of above model is that I thought that each `relu` activation will fit a local linear line, and slowly connect all the neurons to form a quadratic line.

In the end, I managed fit it by using an activation of `lambda x:x**2` on the output layer, However, that is because I know the function is an x**2.

So my question is,  without knowing the true function, how do I train a neural network to fit a non-linear curve?

Comment: There isn't any theoretical reason behind why your NN can't fit a quadratic function. Neural networks with non-linear activation functions ( like ReLU ) can approximate any function, see the [Universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.

Note, I use larger learning rate and an early stop (with 300 patience of total 2000 epochs).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_x = np.linspace(0, 80, 160)
train_y = train_x**2

test_x = np.linspace(80, 100, 40)
test_y = test_x**2


model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)]
)

loss = tf.keras.losses.mse
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2)

early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=300, restore_best_weights=True)

model2.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=tf.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError())
model2.fit(tf.expand_dims(train_x, -1), train_y, epochs=2000, verbose=1, callbacks=[early_stop])

train_pred = model2.predict(train_x)
test_pred = model2.predict(test_x)

plt.scatter(train_x, train_y, c='blue', label='train x')
plt.scatter(test_x, test_y, c='green', label='test x')
plt.scatter(train_x, train_pred, c='red', label='train pred')
plt.scatter(test_x, test_pred, c='orange', label='test pred')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[Training and test results photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX5fE.png)